# Request.QueryString with "&" within it

Tags: asp.net, request.querystring

I am trying to read a querystring and then use this to run a query and display the results for that variable. Very simple.

Unfortunately some of the names have special characters within them and as a result I am not using the full name when running the query on the second page.

i.e. name might be equal to "chas & dave", but the querystring is only giving me back "chas" on the second page and when I search for chas I get no results. Any tips, I seem to have two characters causing an issue "&" and "#".

```
<asp:hyperlinkcolumn datatextfield="merchant_name"
    datanavigateurlfield="merchant_name"
    datanavigateurlformatstring="writing_out.aspx?id={0}"
    headertext="Merchant Name" />
```

Comment: using special characters in URL is a very bad idea either way... Never ever use characters like that.

Comment: thanks, any advice on what to use as an alternative? currently using the standard hyperlinkcolumn within a datagrid.

Comment: before appending `query string` you can convert those to `Base64` for example, and when read `query string`, convert them to pure string

Comment: Why not post the values using a form instead of using URLs?

Comment: it is based on a selection by the user from within a datagrid

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) as follows

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string url)
```

and use that.

For more details
http://www.dotnetperls.com/httputility

Comment: sorry i can see the examples on the page provided, but cant get it to work within my datagrid. I have posted the hyperlink column code above. how would i modify this?

Comment: @Barry you can use databound event to change the url. You can change the values before binding to the grid or any control.

Comment: sorry, i am a bit confused. Are you suggesting i need to create a datatable, add a column which has the encoded URL and then use this field to assign to the datanavigateurlfield property?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
<HeaderTemplate>
    Merchant Name
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="mer_name" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "acc_dec.aspx?id=" + HttpUtility.Urlencode(Eval("merchant_name").ToString())  %>' Text='<%# container.dataitem("merchant_name") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: bascially the answer is use the hyperlink control within a template column.